Desktop freezes for 30 seconds after system alert/beep
Every time the system would normally beep in either mate-terminal or caja (autocomplete beep in mate-terminal, scrolling past top/bottom in caja) the desktop freezes for 30 seconds. A double beep (eg from typing "ll [tab][tab]" in the shell) will freeze for 60 seconds. This occurs whether or not sound alerts are enabled.
There's nothing in logs, and while the mouse moves all keyboard and mouseclick activity is buffered up until the freeze period's over. Terminal and desktop panel (clock, system monitor) activity also freezes. Any ssh sessions from other machines respond in real time during the freeze.
Mostly-fresh system, installed from USB just a week ago.  Intel Core i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz quad, 5955628 kB, swapon -v reports 4G and 224.3M, Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen graphics and audio (latter usually disabled), C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8738/CMI8768 PCI Audio. Video and audio both play fine otherwise, first noticed the fault when fiddling with Pipewire (and have reverted all config changes since then) but don't have any idea whether or not this was lurking before then; the machine's set aside for playing media, so terminal work's unusual. Issue is independent of whichever audio device is selected.
Would LOVE to know what broke, this is taking me right back to 2003.
